# Bokeh vertical bar position misalign with ticker

Tags: python, bokeh

Here is a snippet plotting some vBars (jupyter notebook):

```
import random
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, FactorRange, Range1d
from bokeh.models.glyphs import VBar
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook

# data
data = {'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []}
for i in range(1, 10+1):
    data['x'].append(i)
    data['y'].append(random.randint(1, 100))
    data['z'].append(random.uniform(1.00, 1000.00))

source = ColumnDataSource(data)
xdr = FactorRange(factors=[str(x) for x in data['x']])
ydr = Range1d(start=0, end=max(data['y'])*1.5)

f = figure(x_range=xdr, y_range=ydr, plot_width=1000, plot_height=300, tools='',
           toolbar_location='above', title='title', outline_line_color='gray')

glyph = VBar(x='x', top='y', bottom=0,
             width=0.8, fill_color='blue')
f.add_glyph(source, glyph)

f.add_tools(HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ('time', '$x{0}'),
        ('value', '@' + 'y' + '{0}'),
        ('money', '@z')
    ],
    mode='vline'
))


output_notebook()
show(f)
```

After passing the `x_range` && `y_range`, the vertical bars misalign with the ticker position:-

[image]

In normal case without the `x_range` && `y_range`, it works fine:-

[image]

I wonder what is the parameter governing the vbar position? Why they 'moved' after receiving custom ticker names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It misaligned because of the FactorRange. Not exactly sure why... I replaced this by using the min and max values of the ColumnDataSource and this works fine.

```
import random
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, FactorRange, Range1d
from bokeh.models.glyphs import VBar
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show

# data
data = {'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []}
for i in range(1, 10+1):
    data['x'].append(i)
    data['y'].append(random.randint(1, 100))
    data['z'].append(random.uniform(1.00, 1000.00))

source = ColumnDataSource(data)
ydr = Range1d(start=0, end=max(data['y'])*1.5)

f = figure(x_range=(min(source.data['x'])-0.5, max(source.data['x'])+0.5), y_range=ydr, plot_width=1000, plot_height=300, tools='', toolbar_location='above', title='title', outline_line_color='gray')

glyph = VBar(x='x', top='y', bottom=0,
             width=0.8, fill_color='blue')
f.add_glyph(source, glyph)

f.add_tools(HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ('time', '$x{0}'),
        ('value', '@' + 'y' + '{0}'),
        ('money', '@z')
    ],
    mode='vline'
))

show(f)
```

Comment: Okay right, urm, actually I don't really know what FactorRange is doing at all. I added `f.xaxis[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = len(source.data['x'])` to achieve each  tick for each bar.

Answer (score 0):

I also came accross this issue and noticed the cause behind this issue:
Your data suggests a numeric x axis while the factor range is initialized as a categorical axis (your are using strings).

If you want to have a categorical axis your data needs to be adjusted accordingly

```
data['x'].append(str(i))
```

instead of

```
data['x'].append(i)
```